# How can I use read/write streams with a JSON file?

Tags: node.js, json

I have a rather large JSON file that stores user information, and when my server starts it loads the entire file into memory. Obviously, this is not ideal. I have looked into using read/write streams, but I can't seem to understand quite how they'd work.

The data in the JSON file is formatted as such:

```
"accountName": {
    "favoriteColor": "blue"
}
```

The process currently goes in this order:

1. Server starts, and data.json is loaded into a variable (`dataVar`),
2. User `johndoe` logs in, and their data is used to make an object.
3. The user changes their object's data, and `dataVar` is updated.
4. Server autosaves to the `data.json` file with the new contents.

I want to continue being able to access user data as needed, without loading everything into memory. I assume there are stream equivalents of things like `dataVar.johndoe`, but I can't seem to find that information.

Comment: On NPM, search for "JSON stream" and you will find some modules that can read your JSON as a stream and, depending upon the format, present you with each object one at a time.

Comment: Actually, reading your question again, you need a small database.  If you want to "update" some data in a large dataset without reading the dataset into memory, then you will want a database.  JSON is the wrong format for storing something you're trying to update portions on the fly.  This is what databases are made for.  This is NOT what JSON is made for.